# How are clock cycles and clock rate inverses?

Tags: computer-science

So I'm trying to understand this simple math formula, but I can't wrap my ahead about what it means to be an "inverse".

So for example, a CPU execution time for a program is given by the formula:

$$\text{CPU execution time} = \text{CPU Clock Cycles for a Program} \times \text{Clock cycle times}$$

But then they said clock rate and clock cycle times are inverses, and this is where I start to get confused. The clock rate is the frequency, and the clock cycle time is the time period for one clock cycle, which runs in a constant time. So how are they inverses? Because the above equation can be written as:

$$\text{CPU Execution Time} = \frac{\text{CPU Clock Cycles for a Program}}{\text{Clock Rate}}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$f=\frac{1}{T}$$
$$T=\frac{1}{f}$$
Where $f$ is the frequency and $T$ is the time period of a cycle. This means that the reciprocal of the time period is the frequency and vice versa.

Comment: Is this just like a property/rule?

Comment: Yes - frequency is defined as the amount of cycles in one time period. This is as a result of its definition.